# Parsing invalid JSON file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to load a data in an invalid JSON format into a dict

```
import StringIO
import json
with open("busdata1.json", "r") as busdata:
    #json.load(busdata)
    #busdata = open("busdata.json", "r")

    # Initialize an empty StringIO file.
    databuf = StringIO.StringIO()
    # Read the original busdata file one line at a time.
    for line in busdata:
        #print line
        # Write the read line into the StringIO file.
        databuf.write(line)

        # Did we reach the end of a top-level dictionary?
        if line == '}\n':
            # Set the StringIO to enable reading from its beginning.
            databuf.seek(0)
            # Read the single top-level JSON dictionary.
            data = json.load(databuf)

            # Discard the current StringIO object.
            databuf.close()

            # Initialize a new empty StringIO object.
            databuf = StringIO.StringIO()
            # Now data can be used as a normal Python dictionary.

            # One example: lists the keys of the data dictionary.
            print data.keys()

    # Discard the Str
    databuf.close()
```

The code does not print the keys as expected. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe that it's not valid JSON?

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `busdata1.json`?

Comment: this is what the content look like

Comment: {
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "headers" : {
      "paging" : {
        "startIndex" : 0,
        "pageSize" : 28,
        "moreData" : false
      }
    }
  },
  "body" : [ {
    "recordedAtTime" : "2016-09-13T23:12:15.014+03:00",
    "validUntilTime" : "2016-09-13T23:12:45.014+03:00",
    "monitoredVehicleJourney" : {
      "lineRef" : "3",
      "directionRef" : "1",
      "framedVehicleJourneyRef" : {
        "dateFrameRef" : "2016-09-13",
        "datedVehicleJourneyRef" : "http://data.itsfactory.fi/journeys/api/1/journeys/3_2230_1028_3615"
      },

Comment: i fixed the problem already. thanks

Comment: If you fixed it yourself, consider **posting a self-answer** and then **accepting it** so that the Stack Overflow engine treats this question as "answered".